# Fundamental group of circle union a line

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be the union of the unit circle centered at 0 and the line segment between the points $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$. What is the universal covering of $X$? Compute the fundamental group of $X$.

**My Attempt:**

The fundamental group seems easy enough. Since the line segment between the two points has the point $(1,0)$ as its deformation retract, the fundamental group of $X$ will simply be the fundamental group of the circle which is $\mathbb{Z}$.

As for the universal cover, can we take the usual covering of the circle which is $\mathbb{R}$? Is there a way to formally show this?

Comment: The universal cover will look like $A \cup B$ where $A$ is the $y$-axis and $B$ is the set of $\{(t,n) : t \in \Bbb R, n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet can you explain?

Comment: Oh sorry I was thinking to a different space (I was thinking to the union of a circle with a tangent line). But are you sure about the fundamental group ? If seems to me that  $X$ retracts on a wedge of two circles.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet How do you figure? I thought any line was null-homotopic, so it can be homotoped to a point. So all we are left with is the circle. Is this bad logic?

Comment: You are right, but when you do this there is still a little portion of circle which will become a full circle. For example move the line so that $X$ becomes $S^1$ with the vertical segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$. Now, you can retracts this segment and you see that you have indeed two circles intersecting in one point. This gives $\pi_1(X)$ is the free group on two generators.

Comment: @nicholas First the line has length 1 not 2 . Secondly, you can’t deform retract by attaching the line like that .

Comment: Isn't this just a 1-sphere with a whisker?

Comment: @Randall yes, exactly!

Comment: @Nicholas : did you mean $(0,2)$ instead of $(2,0)$ ? This changes everything.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet No, I meant what I typed.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts : Sorry I didn't read it correctly. I'll delete my comments if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\widetilde{X}$ denote the universal covering of $X$. Then we can write $\widetilde{X}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\widetilde{X} = \{(x,0)\in\Bbb{R}^2~:~x\in\Bbb{R}\} \cup \{(n,t)\in\Bbb{R}^2~:~n\in\mathbb{Z}, \; 0\leq t \leq 1\}.$$

A picture of $X$ and $\widetilde{X}$ is below. One should be able to construct the covering map from these descriptions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Adam. This makes sense. How about the fundamental group. Am I right in saying it is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, the fundamental group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @adam lowrance wouldn’t The real line work as well? Since this spiky space can be retracted to it

Comment: The real line is not the universal cover of $X$ because a covering map must be a local homeomorphism. Informally, the point $(1,0)$ in $X$ locally has a "Y" shape and so the same must be true of its preimage in any covering space. On the other hand, one can prove that $X$ deformation retracts onto the circle $S^1$, and so $\pi_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. A major part of the proof that $\pi_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ involves the universal cover of $S^1$, which is the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: +1.  Was trying to figure out how to say what @AdamLowrance posted but it's already a great answer.